# IOS what method is called when keyboard pops up

Tags: ios

I am making a custom IOS keyboard. I was wondering if there is any method that is called whenever the user selects the keyboard, thus making it pop up on screen. This is because I want to run some code whenever the keyboard pops up.

Answer (score 0):

No method is called.  A notification is posted though.  You can read more about it in the [Managing the Keyboard](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html) section of the [Text Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/).

Comment: I am making a keyboard extension (therefore allowing the keyboard to be used anywhere) would the notification system work for that too?

Comment: I assume that would be different.  You may want to add those details to the question.  You can always try the notifications and see if they work, however.

Answer (score 0):

The notification: `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` is called.  You can create an observer to this method that triggers a function for both actions like this:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardDidShow:"), name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)

NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardDidHide:"), name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)


func keyboardDidShow(notification: NSNotification) {
  print("Keyboard shown")
}

func keyboardDidHide(notification: NSNotification) {
  print("Keyboard hidden")
}
```

Comment: The #selector syntax is probably a better choice than using strings.

Comment: Remember to add the observers on viewWillAppear, and remove them on viewDidDisappear.  You can end up will multiple view controllers listening to the same notification, even if they are not visible.